# Unity 4.6 and Android API level 8

Tags: android, api, unity-game-engine, levels

I believe Android API level 8 was dropped starting with Unity 4.5, which made it unlikely to be able to continue publishing Unity developed apps on the Nook app store. Any time I submit an app now is rejected because they still use Android API level 8. Now that I'm using Unity 4.6, I can't even revert to an earlier version of Unity and compile for Android API 8. Is this situation a problem for anyone else? Just curious.

Comment: Is building against api8 a requirement? it considered best practice to build against highest possible api and use a minimum supported api

Comment: If I submit an app to the Nook app store with a level higher than API 8, it gets rejected with a note telling me to downgrade to API level 8. Unity has stopped supporting API level 8, which means I can't develop apps any longer for Nook, or at least until they upgrade something on their end.

Comment: I accessed my rejected app on the Nook store and unchecked the Nook Color. I think that was the reason for the rejection. I believe the Nook Color is the only one using API level 8 now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't something that one would expect to be "fixed" in future.  API 9 (Gingerbread) added a number of improvements to the NDK, including adding support for x86.

Intel has been working [very closely](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/08/15/unity-android-support) with Unity, and their partnership has resulted in, amongst other things "...Native Android support for Intel architecture in Unity* 4.x and Unity* 5"."

API 8 didn't support the NDK on x86. Additionally:

- API 8 (Froyo) now represents less than 1% of all Android devices
- API 9 added additional features relevant to Unity, such as higher screen resolutions.
- Google recommends API 14+ (which represents over 84% of all Android devices)

While I suspect that NDK enhancements were the driving cause of dropping API 8 support, you can see there is very little reason for Unity to keep investing in API 8 support.

Note: Most hardware supported by 2.2+ was also supported by 2.3+, which is why API 8 is on so few devices now. Of those devices that didn't get 2.3, most are too dated to run the majority of Unity applications. I suspect the Nook Color would fall into that category with a nearly decade old GPU, the PowerVR SGX520.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I decided to go into the Nook developer site and revise my app submission by unchecking the Nook Color tablet, which I believe is the only one that uses API 8. This submission and a new app submission should hopefully make it through the approval process now. It was my dumb mistake by not doing this in the first place.